# Node disconnected errors in Kafka Streams API

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have creates Kafka Consumer code using Kafka Streams API and I'm able to fetch the records from Kafka Topic successfully and able to process those.

I'm seeing below error in the application logs that is showing as "Node -2 disconnected", but still there is no impact and kafka streams API is fetching transactions successfully from kafka topic.

*org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [AdminClient clientId=consumer-5322b972-1ef9-4976-b7fa-39a934374757-admin] Node -2 disconnected.*

Can someone let me know what this error means and is there any way we can avoid these errors. I created Kafka Consumer code using Spring cloud Streams and Kafka Streams

Answer (score 0):

It simply means your client disconnected from a broker. Could happen for many reasons, such as a temporary network blip.

If you have more than one replica of your data that's in sync, then the consumer will continue to work

Comment: Is there any chance that network will get reconnected with the broker. I'm not able to sure that network gets reconnected as there is no application logs.

Comment: Kafka sometimes self heals itself, sure. But not if a broker server crashes. You posted an application log above, so I don't understand the question. And Kafka servers have logs of their own